# Using an ArrayList to output perimeters of triangles

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program that takes in the different sides of a triangle, error-checks to make sure they would be valid, and then outputs them using an ArrayList.

I want it to look something like this...

"Perimeter of triangle t1 is 24."

"Perimeter of triangle t2 is 30"

The ArrayList is my main issue here, I think (probably have more issues). Below, I just tried my best to implement the ArrayList, but obviously couldn't get it. Also, how would I write/change my toString function, so that it would also contain the name of the object created in main (i.e. t1, t2, etc.)?

Thanks for looking!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tri {

public static void main(String []args){

    Triangle t1 = new Triangle(7, 5, 4);
    Triangle t2 = new Triangle(9, 6, 1);

    System.out.println(t1.perimeter());
    System.out.println(t2.perimeter());

    ArrayList<Triangle>allTriangles = new ArrayList<Triangle>();

}

public static double totalPerimeter( ArrayList<Triangle>a ){

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString( a.toArray()));

    for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

        System.out.println( a.perimeter[i]);

    }
}


class Triangle{

    public Triangle( double a, double b, double c ){

        this.sideA = a;
        this.sideB = b;
        this.sideB = c;

        if (checkSides() == true){}
    }

    public double getA(){
        return sideA;
    }

    public double getB(){
        return sideB;
    }

    public double getC(){
        return sideC;
    }

    public Triangle setA( double a ){

        sideA = a;
        return this;

    }

    public Triangle setB( double b ){

        sideB = b;
        return this;

    }
    public Triangle setC( double c ){

        sideC = c;
        return this;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return "Perimeter of triangle is " + perimeter;
    }

    public double perimeter(){

        if (checkSides() == true)

        perimeter = (sideA+sideB+sideC);
        return perimeter;

    }

private boolean checkSides(){

            if (!(sideA+sideB>sideC) && (sideA+sideC>sideB) && (sideB+sideC>sideA)){
                die("Not valid sides of triangle.");
                return false;
            }

            else return true;

        }

        public void die( String msg ){
            System.err.println( "\nFatal error: " + msg );
            System.exit( 1 );
        }

        private double perimeter;
        private double sideA;
        private double sideB;
        private double sideC;

}
```

Comment: What's not working about this? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry about that, my problems are in the totalPerimeter function. length and perimeter cannot be resolved to a field.

Comment: I would recommend iteration like: `for(Triangle triangle : a){}` in totalPerimeter.  No need to try to work with it as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your code should be:

```
        import java.util.*;

        public class Tri {

        public static void main(String []args){

            Triangle t1 = new Triangle(7, 5, 4);
            Triangle t2 = new Triangle(9, 6, 1);

            System.out.println(t1.perimeter());
            System.out.println(t2.perimeter());

            ArrayList<Triangle>allTriangles = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
            allTriangles.add(t1);
            allTriangles.add(t2);

            System.out.println(totalPerimeter(allTriangles));

        }

        public static double totalPerimeter( ArrayList<Triangle>a ){

            double tp = 0.0;

            for(Triangle t : a) {
                System.out.println( "peri : " +  t.perimeter());
                tp += t.perimeter();

            }

            return tp;

        //    for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        //
        //        System.out.println( a.perimeter[i]);
        //
        //    }
        }


        static class Triangle{

            public Triangle( double a, double b, double c ){

                this.sideA = a;
                this.sideB = b;
                this.sideB = c;

                if (checkSides() == true){}
            }

            public double getA(){
                return sideA;
            }

            public double getB(){
                return sideB;
            }

            public double getC(){
                return sideC;
            }

            public Triangle setA( double a ){

                sideA = a;
                return this;

            }

            public Triangle setB( double b ){

                sideB = b;
                return this;

            }
            public Triangle setC( double c ){

                sideC = c;
                return this;
            }

            public String toString(){

                return "Perimeter of triangle is " + perimeter;
            }

            public double perimeter(){

                if (checkSides() == true)

                perimeter = (sideA+sideB+sideC);
                return perimeter;

            }

        private boolean checkSides(){

                    if (!(sideA+sideB>sideC) && (sideA+sideC>sideB) && (sideB+sideC>sideA)){
                        die("Not valid sides of triangle.");
                        return false;
                    }

                    else return true;

                }

                public void die( String msg ){
                    System.err.println( "\nFatal error: " + msg );
                    System.exit( 1 );
                }

                private double perimeter;
                private double sideA;
                private double sideB;
                private double sideC;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `totalPerimeter` function:

1. Since `a` is of type `ArrayList`, it doesn't have a `length` attribute. It *does* however have a `size()` method. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html.
2. Since `a` is of type `ArrayList`, it does not have a `perimeter` array field. Did you perhaps mean something like `a.get(i).perimeter()`?

Answer (score 1):

**First Question:**

> The ArrayList is my main issue here, I think (probably have more
>   issues). Below, I just tried my best to implement the ArrayList, but
>   obviously couldn't get it.

Well, it seems you are missing the `return` statement and have a logical issue in your `totalPerimeter(...)` method.  You need to make sure to add the total perimeter up in a variable, then return that variable.  Also, ArrayList use the method `size()` for length of the list instead of `length`.  Also, you access ArrayList objects using the `get(...)` method.

```
public static double totalPerimeter( ArrayList<Triangle>a ){

    double total = 0.0; //give default value of 0

    for( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){

        total = total + a.get(i).perimeter(); //add up total

    }
    return total;//return it back!
}
```

**Second Question:**

> Also, how would I write/change my toString function, so that it would
>   also contain the name of the object created in main (i.e. t1, t2,
>   etc.)?

I don't think you can do that.  However, you could pass a String to the constructor:

```
private String name;

public Triangle( double a, double b, double c, String variableName){

    this.sideA = a;
    this.sideB = b;
    this.sideB = c;
    this.name = variableName;

    if (checkSides() == true){}
}
```

Then in your `main`:

```
Triangle t1 = new Triangle(7, 5, 4, "t1");
Triangle t2 = new Triangle(9, 6, 1, "t2");
```

You can then update your `toString(...)` method and access the variable `name`.

**Note:**  Final thing to note is that when you `checkSides()` and it returns `false`.  You should `throw` an `Exception` or give the user a warning (ex. print out "WARNING:  invalid sides").